# Gradle build error: Cannot get property 'dirName' on null object

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-build

I am getting gradle build error:

```
Error: Cannot get property 'dirName' on null object
```

I get this error with gradle version 1.3.1 or greater.

When I use gradle version 1.2.3 there is no error.

I google this error but was not able to find any solution. Please help!

My project gradle file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven"  }
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        flatDir { dirs '/usr/local/DexGuard6.1.19/lib' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
        classpath ':dexguard:'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    } 
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven" }
        maven { url "https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com" }
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Comment: `/usr/local/DexGuard6.1.19/lib` exists? Can you remove that section and try again?

Comment: Yes, the directory exists. I use the same code with 1.2.3 and it works but when I change build tools version to 1.3.1 there is this error.

Comment: Could you try: 1. Use `com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0` (perhaps you need to update your SDK first. 2. Ensure to use the latest gradle version (2.9).

Comment: I am using latest gradle version 2.9. I tried changing to 1.5.0 but still the same error.

Answer (score 1):

The Android Gradle plugin is still evolving, with changing tasks and internals. You have to make sure you update the DexGuard Gradle plugin accordingly.

- For Android plugin 1.3.1, you'll need DexGuard 7.0.01 or higher.
- For Android plugin 1.5.0, you'll need DexGuard 7.0.31 or higher